# Cakephp - MissingControllerException Controller class Robots.txt

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.2

My error log is loaded with all of the missing errors, for robots.txt, .css files, .png files and more. The site works, but getting errors. How do I get rid of these errors? I feel like I'm missing something simple, maybe a route or something?

```
2016-05-07 16:11:20 Error: [MissingControllerException] Controller class Robots.txtController could not be found.
#0 /app/webroot/index.php(93): Dispatcher->dispatch(Object(CakeRequest), Object(CakeResponse))
#1 {main}
2016-05-07 16:32:50 Error: [MissingControllerException] Controller class CssController could not be found.
#0 /app/webroot/index.php(93): Dispatcher->dispatch(Object(CakeRequest), Object(CakeResponse))
#1 {main}
```

Comment: So what's your actual question? What's the context? Do these files exist and you expect no errors to be logged? What do the request URLs look like? ...

Comment: Id like the errors to go away. I don't know what the URLs are that trigger the errors.

Comment: I get the same probleme in localhost but code work fine on server from years with different php version and .htaccess files. did you solve this probleme and how please ?

Answer (score 1):

If you try to fetch a resource that doesnt not exist, cake will try to find a controller by that name. So if you try to access /css/whatever and you have no css folder, cake will try to find a CssController to take you to /:controller/:action

Comment: Makes sense. My follow up question would then be, can we know what URL was actually requested so I can chase it down and hopefully stop it ;)

Comment: well, the first looks like yoursite.com/robots.txt. The other one might be /css or /css/*. Make sure you are not getting any 404 in your site to start off.